# Null Pointer Exception onTouchEvent

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null, touch-event

I have a Null pointer Exception on my class onTouchEvent.
This is for a Game called Isola, we need to select a Rect (I check wich rect it is with the makeMove() function.)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // determine if we are in single touch or multi touch mode

    if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
        // for all events take a copy of the data. on the down press

            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

-> 190      touches[0] = true;
            touchx[0] = event.getX();
            touchy[0] = event.getY();
            makeMove();


        } else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            touches[0] = false;
        } 
        }

        // we need to invalidate the display and return true to indicate
        // that we
        // have handled the event and we need an update
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    // we have not handled the event so use the standard event handling



    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

I kon what is a Null pointer Exception, but in this case,I don't understand where it comes from, here is the LogCat :

```
    03-20 20:37:53.002: E/InputEventReceiver(27540): Exception dispatching input event.
03-20 20:37:53.002: E/MessageQueue-JNI(27540): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-20 20:37:53.012: E/MessageQueue-JNI(27540): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 20:37:53.012: E/MessageQueue-JNI(27540):  at com.example.loup_theron_2866207.Isola.onTouchEvent(Isola.java:190)
03-20 20:37:53.012: E/MessageQueue-JNI(27540):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
03-20 20:37:53.012: E/MessageQueue-JNI(27540):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
```

The makeMove method :

```
public void makeMove(){
    try{
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            if(touchx[0] < tableR[j][i] && touchx[0] > tableL[j][i] && touchy[0] < tableB[j][i] && touchy[0] > tableT[j][i]){
                if(tableCheck[j][i] == true){
                    return;
                }
                else if(tableCheck[j][i] == false){
                    tableCheck[j][i] = true;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Null pointer 3");
    }
}
```

Call of the init() :

```
// default constructor for the class
public Isola(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // call the shared init method
    init();
}

// alternative constructor for the class that takes in two arguments
public Isola(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    // call the shared init method
    init();
}

// alternative constructor for the class that takes in three arguments
public Isola(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attr, defStyle);
    // call the shared init method
    init();
}
```

The init :

```
private void init() {
    // create a few paint objects for drawing up to three different colours
    // for our squares
try {
    btn_bottom.setOnClickListener(this);
    red = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    green = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    black = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    white = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    red.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    green.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
    black.setColor(0x00000000);
    white.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    white.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    // initialise all the touch arrays to have just 3 elements as we will
    // only try three
    // touch for now
    touches = new boolean[16];
    touchx = new float[16];
    touchy = new float[16];
    /*
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            tableL[j][i] = 0;
            tableT[j][i] = 0;
            tableR[j][i] = 0;
            tableB[j][i] = 0;
            tableCheck[j][i] = false;

            }
        }
    */
    // initialise a single square that will be shown at all times
    //touchx[0] = 200;
    //touchy[0] = 200;
    // initialise the rectangle
    //squareSelect = new Rect();
    //squareSelect = new Rect(-75, -75, 75, 75);

    square.setStrokeWidth(3);
    square.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    square.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    squareC.setStrokeWidth(3);
    squareC.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    squareC.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Null pointer 2" + e);
}
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you point line 200 to us? (Isola.java)

Comment: `I don't understand where it comes from` - the exception stack trace tells you exactly where - `java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 19:32:59.467: E/AndroidRuntime(17723):    at com.example.loup_theron_2866207.Isola.onTouchEvent(Isola.java:200)`  Isola.java line 200, in the onTouchEvent handler.

Comment: yes I see the Line, but don't understand why..

Comment: I doubt that's the correct line of code.

Comment: @still_learning totally with you

Comment: The line you have highlighted cannot cause an NPE.  Either you have shown the wrong line or the version of the code you have shown is not identical to the version you ran which generated the stacktrace.  I think you should read to understand what a NullPointerException is, then create a new question which correctly describes the problem.

Comment: Please remove all this try catch to any exception , this is the wrost thing you can do to handle some logic error in your code. Trust me, this is probably the motive you are getting a NPE that you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize these variables?
touches, touchx. touchy ?

you should have something like this somewhere in your code:

```
touches=new Boolean[n];
touchx=new Integer[n];
touchy=new Integer[n];
```

Comment: private boolean touches[]; 
private float touchx[];
private float touchy[];

Comment: @user3262670 That's not the initialization, just the declaration.

Comment: ok that's the declaration of your variables... now you have to initialize them because they are arrays. Do as I suggested and it should work ;)

Comment: sorry... yes I did it like you did

Comment: mine : touches = new boolean[16]; 
touchx = new float[16]; 
touchy = new float[16];

Comment: You should look at the line 200 of Isola.java.... that's where the exception is getting thrown!

Comment: Ok so the exception is at this line : touches[0] = true;

Comment: so "touches" is not properly initialized

Comment: but for me, that's good no ? :  touches = new boolean[16];
  touchx = new float[16];
  touchy = new float[16];

Comment: where do you have this code? are you sure it is called BEFORE any ontouch event?

Comment: it is in the init() fuction, so yes it is. (I add this in the post)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error than i realized that i did not initialize the string variable which i use in onTouch method. In your case you may have initialized the array but array items are null so it can not compare them to any value and giving nullpointer?